# Is it safe to run the memez computer trojan in a virtualbox vm?

Tags: virtual-machine, virus, malware

I wanted to run the memez trojan in a virtualbox vm but i don't know if it has a vm escape code in it. i would disconnect the WiFi from the vm before I ran the virus. so is this safe or can it damage my main computer?

Comment: If you don’t already have the malware sample then you have no business running them even on a VM.  We cannot help you with that portion of your question.  We don’t allow users to link to malicious files.

Comment: [Security.SE] is your best bet here - as you might have noticed, questions like this will tend to be above the heads of most users on this site.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are not connected to the Internet (Host machine), then temporarily uninstall VBOX Guest Extensions in the guest machine, and the ensure the is no file sharing between machines.

Now you ca work in the guest without affecting the host machine.

Be careful with ransomware viruses and make certain you ha a complete host machine backup.

This is all in answer to your post.

Comment: Thanks. is there a way I can make sure the VM stays disconnected from wifi?

Comment: While you are examining viruses, make sure the HOST wired and wireless connections are disconnected and the guest cannot be connected at that point. There is no connection available to it. (Don't add a pass through USB wireless of course).